# How to delete custom color ramp in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, color-ramp

I have customized a new color ramp in qgis. Now I want to delete that. I could not find any way to delete this.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. What have you tried so far? Why don't you simply choose a different ramp?

Comment: @Erik, that i can chose, but i want to delete this custom one. You have any idea how to delete this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it from Settings -> Style Manager -> Color ramp, Then select the color ramp that you want to remove and click on the red minus at the top right:

[image]